# How to dynamically set State from Form input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 React parent/child components. The Child Component has a button that adds +1 to the previous state of the Parent Component, and a Form that triggers a `handleChange` function for the `onChange` event.

**The Problem**
From the Form input, I want to trigger a function that sets the State to the previous State, + the input in the Form.

For example, if I write 50 in input and hit submit I want the new state be 100

Here is a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/30mz2vvyo1

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: 50
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return { value: prevState.value + 1 }
    });
  }
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child value={this.state.value} handleChange={this.handleChange} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
     </div>
    )
  }
}


class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <button onClick={this.props.handleChange}>Count + 1</button>
        <div>{this.props.value}</div>

        <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Name:
          <input type="text" onChange={this.props.handleChange} />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: you may need to add the value attr to the input element on Child component like this
<input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.props.handleChange} />

Comment: If i add the value attr, the form becomes a controlled form and then i can't change the input value i think, if i want to change the value to 40 instead of 50 i cant delete the input text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing can be mitigated by;

1. You need to have two different variables in state. value, can hold your value. You also need to hold the current value of the input, let's call it inputNumber.
2. You need to provide an onClick function to your button. In said function, set your state in the following fashion;

Code:

```
this.setState({
  value: this.state.value + this.state.inputNumber,
})
```

After doing these things, it should work as expected.

I have updated your codesandbox, you can take a look at it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/8n94v5w7yj).

Comment: How is the function taking the input data from the form? can be more specific please? What you say makes totally sense to me but i'm unable to reproduce it...

Comment: You need to set ```inputNumber``` in ```handleChange``` function. In there, set ```inputNumber``` too, to ```event.target.value```.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the current state of your code? How does it act, what is the current code? And in what ways does it diverge from what you wish to achieve? @Nullest

Comment: I added a codesandbox, for now it only set the state "value"  to +1 with the button

Comment: I have updated your codesandbox to reflect what I just wrote in the answer, please check the answer. @Nullest